# Kubernetes hostPath safety

Tags: security, kubernetes

I'm designing a game server service using Kubernetes. I decided that the most suitable volume structure for me was hostPath. As a result of my research, I saw that the use of hostPath would cause security problems.

I will create a folder for each pod. And I will link this folder to the pod with hostPath. Users will not have root privileges in the pod. They will be able to start java process with non-root user inside.

Does it really create a security vulnerability for me?

Comment: The biggest problem with hostpath is that a pod can typically move from one host to another, however you haven't explained what you plan to use hostPath for.

Comment: ...or if you have multiple replicas of your Deployment, and they get scheduled on different nodes, they'll each see their local node's disk with a `hostPath:` volume and therefore see different contents.  With some very limited exceptions `hostPath:` is probably not correct.